# recalculate MenuItem.IsChecked

Tags: wpf, binding, menuitem, ischecked

I have a `ContextMenu` on a `DataGrid` and I want to mark a `MenuItem` as checked or unchecked depending on the item in the grid which is right-clicked.

So, I bind the 'IsChecked' property on the `MenuItem` to a property on my ViewModel, and this property is set to true or false by my VM according to item that is right-clicked.

However, turns out that 'IsChecked' property of my `ContextMenu` Item is evaluated only once. It is not evaluated everytime I rightclick an item.

For all subsequent right-clicks, the evaluation carried out the first time is retained.

The getter for property 'IsCheckedonVM' is not fired.

```
<MenuItem Command= IsCheckable="True"
                   IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedonVM}"
                   Header = ".."
    </MenuItem>
```

in the VM:

```
public bool IsCheckedonVM
{
get
{ 
  return selectedItem.IsChecked;
}
set
{
  selecteditem.IsChecked = value;
  OnPropertyChanged("IsCheckedonVM");
}
```

How can I get the `IsChecked` property on my `MenuItem` to be evaluated everytime its rightclicked, so that `IsCheckedonVM` is fetched everytime?

Comment: Try binding a command to your DataGrid`s right click event and executed dedicated logic to determine `IsCheckedonVM` value based on the `SelectedItem` of the grid ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding a command to your `DataGrid`s right click event and executed dedicated logic to determine `IsCheckedonVM` value based on the `SelectedItem` of the grid

Example (using Prism framework) :

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DetermineIsCheckedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
```

And in command:

```
DetermineIsCheckedCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(selectedItem =>
{
    // Do logic and set IsCheckedonVM accordingly
});
```

Comment: I actually want to show in the grid'scontext menu whether the property is checked or unchecked for the right-clicked item.Can't do away with the context menu option.